# Installshield 2009, prevent reinstall of feature during MSI repair

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

I have a MSI package which on first install will install an SQL script onto an SQL Server. This works fine using the SQL Script feature within Installshield.

During a repair of the MSI, the SQL script is re-run. I want to prevent this from occurring, I only want the script to run on install only.

I have tried a number of things to do this:

- Conditions on the Feature - Failed
- Conditions on the component - Failed
- Modifying the local feature selected registry entry at the end of the install - Failed

how can I prevent a feature / component (which is linked to the SQL Script) from been ran on a repair?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a SQL Script in InstallShield is associated to a component ( and therefore a feature ) the condition is on the script itself.  Take a look at the Runtime tab page of the script and you'll see "Script Condition" at the bottom.   This is stored in the ISSQLScriptFile table in the Condition column.

BTW, you might want to consider instead of trying to force the script to not run during a repair to get it to execute gracefully during the repair.   In other words, if the purpose of the script is to create a table, have it do nothing if the table already exists.   This way if the table didn't exist the repair would work and the table would get recreated.   Specifics depend on the nature of the script in question.